# How to std::queue in parallel threads on winapi using std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, std, mutex

I want to make asynchronous writes in stream.
In code below functions `streaming` and `push_stream` runs in parallel threads by using `CreateThread` winapi function. And `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` should lock the `queue` from random access.
But I have some issue with this instance of code. When `queue` pops items, I get `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library` error `__acrt_first_block == header`

```
std::ofstream somestream;
std::queue<std::string> queue;
std::mutex mutexQueue;

void streaming() {
  while (true) {
    if (!queue.empty()) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexQueue);

      while (!queue.empty()) {
          somestream << queue.front();
          queue.pop();
      }
    }
  }
}

void push_stream(std::string str) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutexQueue);
  queue.push(str);
}
```

How to make this kind of asynchronous writes? I've tried `concurrent_queue` but it hasn't a thread-safe item removing.

### UPD

Problem was in `.dll` and `.exe` static linked with RT. Functions implemented in `.exe`, `push_stream` called from `.dll`.
Which cause the [Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _pFirstBlock == pHead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882760/debug-assertion-failed-expression-pfirstblock-phead)

Now issue is fixed.

Comment: `std::queue<std::string>` looks like a bad container choice.

Comment: How about boost::asio? io_service::run + io_service::work + callback functor would work perfectly. No explicit locking and less code.

Comment: The mutex should make this thread-safe, perhaps your problem is elsewhere?

Comment: @DieterLücking you are right. It is because std::string in container.
Is it possible to contain std::string, even without [] access, by this way and don't use the boost?

Comment: The access to `empty()` outside the mutex-protected region is unsafe.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Unsafe in the sense that it gives an unreliable result, but it won't cause a crash.

Comment: **Crash** gives `std::string` in `std::queue`. Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Unsafe in the sense that you get undefined behavior. So even if it doesn't crash now, it might very well start crashing in a future version of the implementation. Just don't use double-checked locking this way. It accomplishes nothing but causing serious maintenance headaches.